# Webpack or React-router messing with external javascript imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am using react in conjunction with react-router and webpack to bundle it all.
My problem is. I am also bound to using 3 external javascript files as plugins in my project. Whenever I change pages with react-router, through the Link component, these javascript files seem to stop working after the first page change. It doesn't matter how I import the files.. Using either the script-loader with an import statement or just putting the `<script>` tags in the base html file itself.
One of these plugins is jquery. The other two are just custom javascript plugins.

UPDATE: I am now aware that I should probably reattach the jquery event listener at each page change. But how should that be done in react since the only pieces of code using jquery are the other two external scripts?

Comment: Please where you able to figure out how to get it to work???